# Make PyCharm alert to reload files when they're changed externally

Tags: pycharm, filesystemwatcher

When switching back to a file open in PyCharm after modifying it with another program, PyCharm doesn't immediately pop-up a message asking whether you want to reload the file from disk or stick to the version in your memory (unlike other editors I've become used to).

All it does is shows a little bar on the top with a tiny reload button; the popup message doesn't display until you try to save the file (by which time it's too late).

I researched a bit; but couldn't find a switch. How can I set the Pycharm to do what I want it to? (The solution shouldn't disable the save dialog window that pops up when you try to close a file with unsaved changes.)

---

#### Screenshots:

PyCharm's tiny message bar:

[image]

Example of expected behaviour:

[image]

Comment: Could you give us a screen shot? I do not seem to be having this problem. Also what _version_ of pycharm you're using would help in the way of resolving this problem.

Comment: When I change a file externally, I don't see any little bar. Could you add a screenshot for that, too?

Answer (score 6):

Please make sure that *Synchronize files on frame activation* is enabled. This is found in [Settings | Appearance and Behavior | System Settings](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/system-settings.html), or Settings | General in older versions of PyCharm (before 4.5).

Also note that problems like this can happen if you're opening a file through a symlink or on a network file system, which can prevent PyCharm from receiving file change notifications correctly.

Comment: i uploaded the snap shot.

Comment: I found this option in `File/Settings/Appearance & behavior/System Settings`  in PyCharm  Community Edition v4.5.2